# Group columns in ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS and cannot seem to figure out how to group columns with its own header.  An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is below:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|        Group 1        |        Group 2        |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| col1  | col2  | col3  | col4  | col5  | col6  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|                                               |
|                 data goes here                |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Obviously, by default I can get `col1` through `col6` as they are the standard columns.  However, I want to add the group names above them.  How would I go about doing this or is there a resource that already shows how to do this?  I have searched Google for about an hour with no prevail.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the pivot grid:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/pivotgrid/simple.html

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the "pivot grid" example no longer exists, but there's now a "Grouped Header Grid" example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/group-header-grid.html

Answer (score 4):

Like Jared said the pivot grid is great if you want ExtJS to do the pivoting for you. You feed the pivot grid a list of records, specify what to group on on the y and x axis and voila.

I think that would work up to a couple of hundred rows but will become problematic with more ( I have done pivot tables in a online research application I wrote in ExtJS with pivoting on millions of records). Also if you want to feed it your entire grouped data yourself you don't want the pivot grid ( I think)

For both cases you need the GroupHeader plugin:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22337-Ext.ux.plugins.GroupHeaderGrid-(v1.3)

Good luck with any 1 you choose, both are great

Rob

Comment: I actually came across this after looking at Keylan's recommendation.  The PivotGrid is good when you need a pivot table, which in this particular case, I needed.  However, I have another table that I'm working on right now that is not a pivot table and this is great!  Thanks for the information!  Now if only I could find some decent documentation on GroupHeaderGrid...

Comment: @Jared BTW if you use Ext 3.0 you should use http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?76322-GroupHeaderGrid-Grouped-grid-column-headers
3.1+ includes the plugin in the SDK, look for examples in the examples/ux folder. I like documentation by example the best anyway :)